# Move Data in Vertical Cells To Horizontal Cells in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am using excel 2007

I have a excel sheet with around 1200 records with following structure...

WHAT CAN BE EASIEST WAY TO DO THIS ?

For easy understanding, Adding image :

[image]

Comment: I think you can delete the text example and leave only the image

Comment: Unless you want to do it manually, I think **easiest** in Excel 2007 would be a VBA solution.  Or you could upgrade your program and use Power Query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Can I have a sample VBA solution. as I am not much expert in Excel..

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Or How to use Power Query For my this issue ? ( I can try it on my friend's laptop as he have laptop with MS Office 2013 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula Used as follows (Giving solution here so in future members can use it)

The formula is : In empty cell after Treasurer Column,

```
 =If($a2="","",a2) // copy over next 4 columns to give the District, Branch, Pre name, address, mobile elements as =If($a2="","",a2), =If($b2="","",b2), =If($c2="","",c2), =If($c2="","",c3), =If($c2="","",c3), =If($c2="","",c4)

 =if($d2="","",d2) // copy over next 2 columns for Secretary details like =if($d2="","",d2), =if($d2="","",d3), =if($d2="","",d4)

 =if($g2="","",g2) // copy over next 2 columns for Treasurer details like =if($g2="","",g2), =if($g2="","",g3), =if($g2="","",g4)
```

Now **Select All New Formula Cells** in a row after Treasurer column >> **Drag Down** Till All Records....

Then Copy all these down to the bottom of your data

Either **copy / paste special >> values** to somewhere else and

Then **sort by District / Branch / Pres to drop the blank rows**

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment request, here is a `Power Query` solution.

To enter the code:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.

**Algorithm**

- Fill in (fill down) the blank rows for the `District` and `Branch` columns
- `Group` by `District` and `Branch`
- For each Group, extract as a delimited string the entries for `President`, `Secretary` and `Treasurer`.
- Create the appropriate column names and split the delimited strings into separate columns.

*If you have more officers, or more items per officer/position, or more columns before you get to the officer columns, it should be relatively simple to modify the code to take that into account.*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"District", Text.Type}, {"Branch", type text},
         {"President", type text}, {"Secretary", type text}, {"Treasurer", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"District", "Branch"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"District", "Branch"},{
        {"President", each Text.Combine([President],";")},
        {"Secretary", each Text.Combine([Secretary],";")},
        {"Treasurer", each Text.Combine([Treasurer],";")}
        }),

colHeaderSuffix = {"","Addr","Mobile"},
PresidentCols = List.Accumulate(colHeaderSuffix, {}, (state, current) => List.Combine({state, {"President " & current}})),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "President", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), PresidentCols), 

SecretaryCols = List.Accumulate(colHeaderSuffix, {}, (state, current) => List.Combine({state, {"Secretary " & current}})),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Secretary", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), SecretaryCols),

TreasurerCols = List.Accumulate(colHeaderSuffix, {}, (state, current) => List.Combine({state, {"Treasurer " & current}})),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter2", "Treasurer", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), TreasurerCols) 

in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter3"
```

**Original Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for great solution and giving important time.... I solved it as given in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your excel pc will be able to handle it but you can use the [Paste Transpose][1].

You copy everything, (my advice, go to a new spreadsheet, but you can use the same one),
and then you past it use past transform

[image]

*edit

after you edited your question with the example you might want to use the past transform and then use pivot table